Not able to inspect Docker Volume mountpoint
I have been learning about Docker volumes, so I created a Docker volume and mounted it to a directory in the container. I was actually interested to know in what format Docker volume stores data, so I decided to inspect the Docker volume.
ggarg1@macos-GJQHF5XXX Docker-and-Kubernetes % docker volume inspect tmp-volume-mount-demo
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2024-10-06T19:10:10+05:30",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": {},
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/containers/storage/volumes/tmp-volume-mount-demo/_data",
        "Name": "tmp-volume-mount-demo",
        "Options": {},
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]

I was expecting that Docker must be storing the volume data at the mount point, so I decided to inspect it.
ggarg1@macos-GJQHF5XXX lib % cd /var/lib/containers/storage/volumes/tmp-volume-mount-demo/_data
cd: no such file or directory: /var/lib/containers/storage/volumes/tmp-volume-mount-demo/_data

In fact, the directory /var/lib/containers doesn't exist. Can anyone help me why I am not able to cd to this location, and if Docker indeed does store the volume data at mountpoint?

You shouldn't usually be looking at the container internals in /var/lib/docker or /var/lib/containers, and the internal storage won't affect your application code at all.  Your prompt hints you're on a MacOS system, which intrinsically will require a Linux VM, and Docker named-volume storage will be inside that VM.  Does Access Docker volume Mountpoint with Docker for Mac have the information you need?  How is this related to your code?

@DavidMaze Why does macOS need to boot a Linux VM to run Docker? Both macOS and Linux are Unix based operating systems, right?

Yes, but they're not the same kernels; you can't directly use Linux binaries on a MacOS host, and you can't use the Linux-specific syscalls that Docker needs to set up its isolation environments.  (You similarly can't directly run, say, Docker on FreeBSD, for the same reasons.)
